# Gigabyte Motherboard : black screen, inspite of single beep and responding keyboard

Tags: boot, bios, motherboard

My desktop booths with a single beep: indicating BIOS check success.

CPU Fan keeps running, keyboard capslock and num lock respond when I boot it.But all I can see is black screen. I have tried different screen and different VGA cable as well.

I am out of all ideas as of what to check. Any suggestions or guidance is most welcomed.

- Motherboard : GA-H81M-DS2 rev 2.1
- Processor : Intel i3-4130

Note : Last resort suggested was to use 512Mb graphics card to reroute the display, but that's an educated guess and I don't want to bet more money without knowing if that will really solve my problem.

Thanks

**Update :**
I was able to see bios screen but only for few seconds and then whole screen scrambles to colourful noise(Please refer to video for more details) and keyboard(Numlock/caps lock) stops responding.

Also, I noticed that after multiple attempts (probably due to heat over time) the functional screen time was increased to a couple of minutes, but ultimately it did scramble.

I have also tried CMOS reset multiple time, same outcome.

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DpLKaFuVltVYvy6BmOxpWtzNjtA76S9p/view?usp=share_link)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Perhaps the onboard graphics support has been disabled. Try resetting the BIOS along with an update.

Comment: Im no expert but according to https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/forums/threads/my-gigabyte-motherboard-beeps.60980/1 beep might mean OK, or it could mean a memory error depending on the BIOS manufacturer?

Comment: What CPU are you using?

Comment: @davidgo : I checked the motherboard beep code, 1 beep means all ok.

Comment: @zomega intel i3 5th gen (I dont remember the exact number, I might have to remove the thermals to check the same)

Comment: @Bib : I tried that, no change (note: I have never used dedicated graphics card on this system)

Comment: You need to update the question with details of when it last worked and what cpu you have installed. It's possible the iGPU has been blown. Are you really using VGA rather than DP/HDMI etc? Does the monitor support different connection? Is it setup for the correct one?

Comment: @Bib  I am using VGA. As you can see on update comment iGPU seems to be working. But then I am no expert.

Comment: I would say your iGPU and hence cpu is borked. Try reseating it and the memory. Make sure to take proper esd precautions lest you completely fry it.

Comment: You have to try a different graphics card, monitor and video cable. This issue cannot be solved in an other way. It does not make sense to make wild guesses. You have to try different hardware.

Answer (score 4):

I looked into the [manual on page 25](https://download1.gigabyte.com/Files/Manual/mb_manual_ga-h81m-ds2_e.pdf) and there is an "Initial Display Output" setting in the BIOS. The default is "PCIe 1 Slot".

So you might think if a graphics card is not found then it will switch to onboard graphics.

But I found this [reddit.com post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gigabytegaming/comments/n62sqc/gigabytes_initial_display_output_setting/) and he says that the motherboard does not automatically switch to onboard VGA.

So you have two options:

1. buy a graphics card
2. or (see screenshot in manual): press del, then 3x right, (perhaps down), (perhaps enter), +, (perhaps enter), F10 to save, (perhaps left or right), enter

If you try a little you can get it running without buying a graphics card.

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts, and thank you again for sharing this. I will definitely try this on weekend and share my findings.

Comment: please refer to my "update" comment for updates.